# WPF Binding how to get object reference

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a ListView showing a list of Accounts using MVVM & a custom template and working fine
Now on clicking the Acct Name, we need to execute a custom action which requires the current Acct object

Is there a way to set the Label.Tag property to the Acct object ?

the xaml def is below
env is vs2010 .net 4.0 c#

```
<ListView Name="lv1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4"
    ItemsSource="{Binding AccountsList}"
    Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="/asm1;component/Images/Icons/pdf1.png" Width="12" Height="12" />
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}" Margin="0,0,25,0" 
                    ContextMenu="{x:Null}" Name="lblacctItem" 
                    MouseDoubleClick="lbl_MouseDoubleClick" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Background="Transparent" 
                Width="{Binding (FrameworkElement.ActualWidth), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ScrollContentPresenter}}" 
                ItemWidth="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}" 
                MinWidth="{Binding ItemWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
                ItemHeight="{Binding (ListView.View).ItemHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

Comment: `MouseDoubleClick="lbl_MouseDoubleClick"` is not a good approach, here you going to implement business logic in the code behind and it's against MVVM principle. If you want to stick to MVVM pattern consider using Commands instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing MVVM and code behind.

You should create a command behavior ([Link](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=734)) to label. Then you should bind CommandParameter to AccObject, and Command to the action you need to execute.

Following should be removed.

```
MouseDoubleClick="lbl_MouseDoubleClick"
```

**Updated as per comments**

As current item is bound to AccObject, simply use Binding in command parameter.

```
CommandParameter = {Binding}
```

Comment: how to get the AccObject is the Question

Answer (score 1):

You can set SelectedItem property to SelectedAccount property of viewmodel.

SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAccount}"
             Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">

Use INotifyPropertyChanged interface on SelectedAccount property.

Thanks,
Rajnikant